# Display plots to specific tabPanles in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny app with a `radioButtons()` widget in the sidebar.

This widget has 3 options `"Home","Sector A","Sector B"`. When the user selects a choice he is navigated to a specific `tabsetPanel()` which consists of some `tabPanels`.

The issue is that I want the plots and the tables I created to be displayed only in the relative `tabPanel` but as you will see they are displayed almost everywhere. More specifically the `tabPanel` `"Two Bars only here"` should display only the 2 bars ONLY there. The same logic for the rest. The tables should be displayed in the respective `"Constituents"` tab and the ohlc charts in the respective `"Index"` tab.

I do not understand why the `if` conditions I use do not restrict this behavior.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)
#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("rad")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabers"),
      plotlyOutput("bars"),
      plotlyOutput("bars2"),
      plotlyOutput("index1"),
      plotlyOutput("index2")
    )
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)
server = function(input, output) {

  output$rad<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("radio", label = "",
                 choices = list("Home" = 1, "Sector A" = 2, "Sector B" = 3), 
                 selected = 1)
  })

  output$tabers<-renderUI({
    # Left last else in here but should not get called as is
    if(input$radio==1){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Two Bars only here",
                 output$bars<-renderPlotly({
                   p <- plot_ly(
                     x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
                     y = c(20, 14, 23),
                     name = "SF Zoo",
                     type = "bar"
                   )
                 }),
                 output$bars2<-renderPlotly({
                   p <- plot_ly(
                     x = c("gir", "ora", "mon"),
                     y = c(20, 14, 23),
                     name = "SF Zoo",
                     type = "bar"
                   )
                 }))
      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio==2){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabB",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents Table Iris only here",
                 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                   datatable(
                     iris)
                 })),
        tabPanel("Index1 only here",
                 output$index1<-renderPlotly({


                   getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

                   df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
                   df <- tail(df, 30)

                   p <- df %>%
                     plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="ohlc",
                             open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
                             high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
                     layout(title = "Basic OHLC Chart")
                 }))
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==3){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents Mtcars only here",
                 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                   datatable(
                     mtcars)
                 })),
        tabPanel("Index2 only here",
                 output$index1<-renderPlotly({


                   getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

                   df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
                   df <- tail(df, 30)

                   p <- df %>%
                     plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="ohlc",
                             open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
                             high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
                     layout(title = "Basic OHLC Chart")
                 }))
      ) 
    }

  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `ui` and `server` functions are to *separate* the interface and the workings of your app. All your outputs are simply placeholders to be filled in by `server`, and this I fear is the source of the confusion. Your radio buttons, for instance, are entirely static and does not need to be set via `server`.

You can easily draw your entire UI and ensure that individual plots only appear in individual panels.

Try this for starters:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio", label = "",
                 choices = list("Home" = 1, "Sector A" = 2, "Sector B" = 3), 
                 selected = 1)
    ),

   ...
)
```

For your panels, the uiOutput should be defined in the renderUI, not separately from the tabset:

```
 output$tabers<-renderUI({
    # Left last else in here but should not get called as is
    if(input$radio==1){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Two Bars only here",
          plotlyOutput('bars'),
          plotlyOutput('bars2')
        )
      )
    } elseif ...
```

The respective renderPlotly calls can then be defined separately under `server`, not nested inside another `renderUI`.

Another approach could be to have 4-5 fixed outputs, but then *hide* unused ones. For this, see the `shinyjs` package.